# Running java applet on web

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

I am trying to run a java applet as web application by using tomcatserver 7.0 with eclipse

applettest.java:

```
  package main;
  import java.applet.*;
  import java.awt.*;

 public class applettest extends Applet{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2119308802277101723L;

public void paint(Graphics g){
  g.drawString("helloworld.",90,100);
  }
}
```

And exported it as a jar file and included in the html file

main.html:

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <div >
 <APPLET CODE="applettest.class"  archive="/desktop/applettest/applettest.jar" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">
 </APPLET>
 </div>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

When I run it on google chrome browser it gives me "the plugin is not supported". Then I tried to run on safari browser and I changed the security setting to allow java. It gives me the following error:

```
      Plugin2Manager calling stopFailed() because of displayable window      sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginEmbeddedFrame[frame0,169,102,800x500,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
     Java Plug-in 11.66.2.17
     Using JRE version 1.8.0_66-b17 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
     User home directory = /Users/reem
     ----------------------------------------------------
     c:   clear console window
     f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
     g:   garbage collect
     h:   display this help message
     l:   dump classloader list
     m:   print memory usage
     o:   trigger logging
     q:   hide console
     r:   reload policy configuration
     s:   dump system and deployment properties
     t:   dump thread list
     v:   dump thread stack
     x:   clear classloader cache
     0-5: set trace level to <n>
     ----------------------------------------------------
```

How can I fix this issue in order to run java applet on web??

Comment: The 'problem' with Chrome will never be fixed (& FF and IE are set to follow suit).  The only real option is to launch the applet free-floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Is there other way to run the applet on other browsers such as firefox and safari

Comment: *"Is there other way to run the applet on other browsers.."*  ... Black Magic?

Comment: So the code above can never work for the other browsers??

Comment: FF is also set to drop support for applets AFAIU.  Don't know about Safari.  But why the enthusiasm for a lot of work getting an applet to work embedded in a (shrinking) handful of browsers, when it can work free-floating launched form *any* browser on a machine with Java installed?

Comment: can you please tell me what are the major steps to run java application using java web start @AndrewThompson

Comment: They are linked from the JWS nfo. page linked in my first comment.  'Deploying a desktop app.' is too broad for an SO comment or answer.

Comment: thank you, I will check it @AndrewThompson